# how to show image on right hand side of table view for iphone

Tags: iphone

i can show image on left hand side of table view but why my right hand side is not working

```
CGRect frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(310 ,10, 50, 50);
UIImageView *   myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bowl.png"];


    myImageView.frame = frame;
    [myImageView release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_dot.png"]];
cell.accessoryView = image;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this code in `willDisplayCell` and it should work. Also remember the default cell already has an imageview, you can just move its frame.

Comment: willDisplayCell is a delegate method in UITableViewDelegate